# error while installing heptio ark (velero) on Azure AKS

Tags: azure, backup, azure-aks

I am trying to install heptio velero (earlier known as Ark) for one of my k8s clusters.

I took the following steps 
**A]install prereq.**
original yaml file [here](https://github.com/heptio/velero/blob/master/examples/common/00-prereqs.yaml)

[image]

**B]install secrets**

kubectl create secret generic cloud-credentials --namespace velero --from-literal AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="" --from-literal AZURE_TENANT_ID="" --from-literal AZURE_CLIENT_ID="" --from-literal AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="" --from-literal AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP="name-of-resource-group-where-my-vm etc created typically starts with MC_ in azure"

**C]apply remaining k8s resources**

[image]
these files are 
[image]

the content of volume snapshot location

```
---
apiVersion: velero.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshotLocation
metadata:
  name: azure-default
  namespace: velero
spec:
  provider: azure
  config:
    apiTimeout: 30
```

and backup storage location

```
---
apiVersion: velero.io/v1
kind: BackupStorageLocation
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: velero
spec:
  provider: azure
  objectStorage:
    bucket: "<blob name for bucket>"" 
  config:
    resourceGroup: "<resource group name of my azure storage>" 
    storageAccount: "<storage account name >"
```

**C]while looking at logs I found following error**

```
Failed to list *v1.VolumeSnapshotLocation: 
v1.VolumeSnapshotLocationList.Items: 
[]v1.VolumeSnapshotLocation: v1.VolumeSnapshotLocation.Spec: 
v1.VolumeSnapshotLocationSpec.Config: ReadString: expects " or n, but found 3,error found in
```

Comment: yes as per their documentation i  created kubectl create secret generic cloud-credentials --namespace velero --from-literal AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="" --from-literal AZURE_TENANT_ID="" --from-literal AZURE_CLIENT_ID="" --from-literal AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="" --from-literal AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP="name-of-resource-group-where-my-vm etc created typically starts with MC_ in azure"

Comment: Yes of course. Due to security reasons I can not paste actual values. Do I need to provide access keys in secrets for my backup storage account

Comment: as per documentation i need to provide AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET  and AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP these values i provided while creating secret and also mentioned same earlier

Comment: sorry, somehow I misread that, just delete these comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error is due to you passing integer, not string to the apiTimeout, try passing a string:

```
apiVersion: velero.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshotLocation
metadata:
  name: azure-default
  namespace: velero
spec:
  provider: azure
  config:
    apiTimeout: "30"
```

[Api spec](https://heptio.github.io/velero/v0.11.0/api-types/volumesnapshotlocation.html#azure) and your error suggest its looking for a string

Comment: thanks it works for me. i am not able to get this error now